# Reputable web application security auditing/verification service

Tags: security, authentication, web-applications

I'm developing a web application (PHP) that may store sensitive/confidential company information and is targeted towards medium to large size businesses.

In developing this application, my team is taking every security measure we can think of, including:

- Sanitizing user input for SQL queries (By using the codeigniter input/database libraries)
- Forcing the use of HTTPS via HTTP-redirects
- Hashing user passwords with the [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) framework (CRYPT_BLOWFISH)
  (also checking passwords are < 72 characters to prevent DoS attacks)
- Using a database to store session data along with quick session expiration ( < 10min), secure sessions (only sent via HTTPS), and encrypted cookies, and matching IP & User Agent
- CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery) tokens
- Using a third party to store and process any credit card data

First, are there any security practices that I may have overlooked? However, my main question is: Are there any reputable auditing bodies/groups/organizations that could audit our application and affirm that we're using the best (or at least industry accepted standard) security measures? We would like to use such an accreditation as a selling-point for our software.

Comment: Along with sanitizing input queries, try forcing data types as well (e.g. if you have a variable `$ID`, force it to be an `int` by casting it: `$ID = int($raw_ID)`).

Comment: Do you salted password hashes as well? Also, I'd re-think IP and user agent matching. IPs can change, and some people use different browsers (or browsers update and change their user agent strings).

Comment: @Blender, the phpass password hashing framework takes care of that. It does create a unique salt for each password, and the salt is actually concatenated onto the resulting hash. See link if you're curious.

Comment: I don't really use PHP (I'm more fond of Python's syntax), but thanks for the info. Didn't know about that framework.

Comment: @Blender, I'm not concerned with a user's session being occasionally invalidated by a changing IP address or browser user agent string somehow suddenly changing mid-session. My users would probably not mind having to occasionally re-authenticate if it led to increased security. Matching the IP & user-agent strings makes it more difficult to session-hijack / cookie theft

Comment: That's about all that I could think of. I've never hired any company to perform a security audit (so I can't really suggest you one), but your webapp seems to be rock-solid.